# multiple-markers in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to locate multiple positions in google map, I'm not good at javascript that's why I'm having trouble in creating an array of multiple locations.
I have created a map which is showing the current position. I want to add some more locations to that.

```
var watchID = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    var optn = {
enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: Infinity,
            maximumAge: 0   
        };
    if( navigator.geolocation )
     navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, fail, optn);
    else
     $("p").html("HTML5 Not Supported");
$("button").click(function(){

    if(watchID)
     navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);

    watchID = null;
    return false;
});

});

function success(position)
{
    var googleLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                        position.coords.longitude);

      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(26.220778, 78.177259);      

    var mapOtn={
zoom:15,
center:googleLatLng,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROAD
    };

    var Pmap=document.getElementById("map");

    var map=new google.maps.Map(Pmap, mapOtn);
    addMarker(map, googleLatLng, "Momo", 
                  "Mamta");
}

function addMarker(map, googleLatLng, title, content){
    var markerOptn={
position:googleLatLng,
map:map,
title:title,
animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
    };

    var marker=new google.maps.Marker(markerOptn);

    var infoWindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: content, 
                                                   position: googleLatLng});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
        infoWindow.open(map);
    });                                                
}

function fail(error)
{
    var errorType={
0:"Unknown Error",
1:"Permission denied by the user",
2:"Position of the user not available",
3:"Request timed out"
    };

    var errMsg = errorType[error.code];

    if(error.code == 0 || error.code == 2){
        errMsg = errMsg+" - "+error.message;
    }

    $("p").html(errMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend by starting by setting up a simple marker using this simple tutorial from the the google maps api documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

on this page we can see the code for creating a simple market in the following function:

```
    function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });
      //Here we can see the code for creating a simple marker below.
      //by using the same logic we can copy the code below and create 
      //another marker on the map.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {121.11,44.543},
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
  }
```